# creating an instance of Date class, not using the depreciated constructor Date(year, month, day), not using third party library

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'm trying to create an instance of the class `Employee`. `Employee` class is a class I came up myself. One of the instance variable in class `Employee` is `Date dateOfJoining`. I tried to pass the argument as `new Date(2015, 10, 1)` and have noticed that this constructor is depreciated. All I want is to create an instance of Date that include year, month and day. I DONT want to use third party library. Could someone please give me a hint? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "justin", 1000, 23, new Date(2015, 10, 1));
```

Comment: You can finagle a date from a calendar.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils i did check Calendar Java Doc but the class only contain two constructors and none of them accept (int year, int month, int day) as arguments. Could you please provide me with a bit more detail? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't let the lack of a constructor kill your plan. Not everything has to be handled on instantiation.

Comment: i c. I will give it a try then. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `java.util.Calendar`, eg in java 8:

```
Date firstOfJan2016TwelvePmUk = new Calendar.Builder()
        .setDate(2016, 1, 1)
        .setTimeOfDay(12, 0, 0)
        .setLocale(Locale.UK).build()
        .getTime();
```

Or in java 7 something like:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2016, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0);
    cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Date date = cal.getTime();
```

If you only want to set year month and day; java 8:

```
Date date = new Calendar.Builder()
        .setDate(2016, 1, 1).build()
        .getTime();
```

java7:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2016, 1, 1, 12);
    Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: beresfordt, thank you very much for the suggestion. I actually thought about this option. but it seems very complicated for what I am trying to achieve, all I want is to create an instance of Date class using three int, i.e. int year, int month, int day, do you have any other alternative solutions that's a bit less complicated?

Comment: updating with an example